# ActiveReports 7 running Report using a Custom Data Provider through the WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight, activereports

I'm currently trying to run an ActiveReports 7 Report using a Custom Data Provider through the WebService. The problem I'm facing is that the service is unable to locate my custom data provider even though the assembly is present in the bin folder. Furthermore, I have the GrapeCity.ActiveReports.config file in my bin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the latest build of [AR7](http://www.componentone.com/Downloads/Search/?q=&product=536&version=7).
Also, you set a new connectionstring to the Webservice in order to set it as a datasource. Here are the links :

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arWLKDocumentWebService.html
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arWLKDataSetWebService.html

Regards,
Mohita